# WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger raise unhendled exception ORA-01407

Tags: oracle, plsql, runtime-error, oracleforms

I am new in `PL SQL` and I am trying to resolve problem with copy-past data from .CVS file to database 
I create a small application which will take data from `.CVS` and past it to database. 
I create a method, but after I compile it's writtend Successfully compiled 
But when I run form I get error

```
WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger raise unhendled exception ORA-01407
```

Does anyone know what this means since I google it and could not find anything ? 
I would be very thankfull

```
declare 
    import_file text_io.file_type; 
  import_file_name varchar2(1000);

  import_log_file text_io.file_type;
  import_log_file_name varchar2(1000);

  vec_importovano number;
  brojac number;
  brojac_redova number;
  linebuf varchar2(5000);

  p_rbr varchar2(4);
  p_polica varchar2(20);
  p_banka varchar2 (20);
  p_kontakt varchar2(20);

  kraj_fajla number;

begin
    import_file_name := :Global.Lokacija_prenosa||:import.naziv_fajla||:Global.Ekstenzija_prenosa;
    import_file := text_io.fopen(import_file_name,'r');
    --p_rbr := 100000;

    delete from zivot_trajni_nalog_ponude where banka is not null;
    commit;

    kraj_fajla := 0;  
    while kraj_fajla = 0 loop
        begin   
    text_io.get_line(import_file, linebuf);

     if brojac_redova>=2 then
         if length(linebuf)>100 then 

            p_rbr:=substr(linebuf, 1, instr(linebuf,';',1,1)-1);
            p_polica:=substr(linebuf, instr(linebuf,';',1,1)+1, instr(linebuf,';',1,2) - instr(linebuf,';',1,1)-1);
            p_banka:=substr(linebuf, instr(linebuf,';',1,2)+1, instr(linebuf,';',1,3) - instr(linebuf,';',1,2)-1);
            p_kontakt:=substr(linebuf, instr(linebuf,';',1,3)+1, instr(linebuf,';',1,4) - instr(linebuf,';',1,3)-1);

        select count(*) 
      into vec_importovano 
      from ZIVOT_TRAJNI_NALOG_PONUDE
      where broj_police=p_polica and p_rbr=redni_broj;

        if vec_importovano=0 then
        insert into ZIVOT_TRAJNI_NALOG_PONUDE values(p_rbr, p_polica, p_banka, p_kontakt);          
        commit;
         end if;
         end if;
     end if;

     EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN kraj_fajla := 1;
     end;

        end loop;  
        update zivot_trajni_nalog_ponude set redni_broj = p_rbr;
            commit;

    text_io.fclose(import_file);
        message('Zavrseno prepisivanje fajla');

end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you got (`ORA-01407`) means that you are trying to update a column (which is set to `NOT NULL`) with a `NULL` value. That won't work. For example:

```
SQL> create table test (id number not null);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (100);

1 row created.

SQL> update test set id = null;
update test set id = null
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01407: cannot update ("SCOTT"."TEST"."ID") to NULL


SQL>
```

The only `UPDATE` in your code is this:

```
UPDATE zivot_trajni_nalog_ponude SET redni_broj = p_rbr;
```

Apparently, `p_rbr` is `NULL`, `redni_broj` won't accept it and you got the error.

What to do? Debug your code and see why `p_rbr` doesn't have a value. A simple "solution" might be

```
   IF p_rbr IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      UPDATE zivot_trajni_nalog_ponude
         SET redni_broj = p_rbr;
   END IF;
```

---

Also, although not related to your problem: don't `COMMIT` within a loop.

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-01407 occurs as you are trying to update/Insert a column to NULL
>   when the column does not accept NULL values.

To find all the "not null" columns in table `ZIVOT_TRAJNI_NALOG_PONUDE`, Please check the DDL of the table.